# nvm use does not switch version of nodejs

Tags: nvm

I have two versions of Node js but I try to switch to 14.20.1 then I get the message below how should I solve this problem? I have tried to delete the folder Nodejs in C:\Program Files it still does not work

```
C:\Users\BETA TECH>nvm list

  * 16.17.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    14.20.1

C:\Users\BETA TECH>nvm use 14.20.1
exit status 1: 'C:\Users\BETA' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

exit status 1: 'C:\Users\BETA' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\BETA TECH>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell and run it as administrator and try again